# I don't know how to change query to not being match with all the names

Tags: regex

I would like to write an regular expression in order to filter the `franklusero06` and present the rest of the names below:

```
franklusero06   
usprodusero1    
usprodusero2    
ukusero2
```

This is my regular expression for it:

```
([A-Za-z]{2,3}(produsero|usero)+[0-9]{1,3})
```

Here you can find code: [code](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=93912)

The problem with this code is to match with all the names, however this is not what I want and I want to match just with the last 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a word boundary to regex:

```
\b([A-Za-z]{2,3}(produsero|usero)+[0-9]{1,3})\b
```

Comment: perfect. What is doing boundary exactly?

Comment: Word boundaries match a location between a word and a non-word characters (or at the beginning/start of a string).

Comment: I am using the REXP with mysql`Sequel Pro`, there seems that `\b` not supported. Can I use ^and $, for the beginning  and end of the REGEXP?!! @Giorgi Nakeuri

Comment: @MaryamPashmi, if the string you search are all on new lines then yes

Comment: I didn't get what do u mean exactly?! But if I understood correctly, my file is log which I each line I am looking for this pattern.

Comment: I mean if you have `usprodusero1  usprodusero2` on one line it will not work

Answer (score 1):

You could clean up the regex some more:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]{2,3}(?:prod)?usero+\d{1,3})\b
```

Does the job just a bit faster.

Comment: what is the difference with you have written with `\b([a-zA-Z]{2,3}(prod)?usero+\d{1,3})\b`  ??

Comment: The ?: prevents catching a second group (prod)